# 500 Error While trying to make a function using a PHP script

Tags: php, mysql, function

I am trying to make a function to search table in database. I do have a script for searching. I want to use this script as a function.

Here is my script.

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['q'])){
    error_reporting(-1);

    $query = $_GET['q'];

    function search_aya($query) {

        include 'core/db.inc.php';

        $dbh  = new mysqli($host, $user, $password,  $database);

        if ($dbh->connect_error) {
            echo 'Unable to connect to database '. $dbh->connect_error;
        } else {



            if ($stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT id, sura, aya, text FROM bn_bengali WHERE MATCH(text) AGAINST(?) "))

                {
                $stmt->bind_param("s", $query);
                // executing the statement
                $stmt->execute();
                // binding the table columns Name and Email to the $Name and Email parameters respectively.
                $stmt->bind_result($id, $sura, $aya, $text);
                /* fetch associative array */

                return $stmt;


            } else {
                    echo "Prepare failed: (" . $dbh->errno . ") " . $dbh->error;
            }
        }

    } //ending function

    $stmt = search_aya($query);
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        echo $sura.'-'.$aya;
        echo $text;
        echo '<hr />';
    } 

} // end isset get q
else
{
     echo '<form action="" ><input type="text" name="q"><button>Search</button></form>';
}
?>
```

It is giving an error saying **"500 - Internal Server Error"**

Can you tell me which is the right way to make a function using this script.

In log file I found something like this,

I think log for this error is

```
2016-04-26 11:19:15: (src/mod_fastcgi.c.3346) response not received, request sent: 990 on socket: tcp:127.0.0.1:9998 for /quran/search_func_array_ret.php?q=hi, closing connection
```

2016-04-26 11:21:31: (src/mod_fastcgi.c.2562) unexpected end-of-file (perhaps the fastcgi process died): pid: 15303 socket: tcp:127.0.0.1:9998 
2016-04-26 11:21:31: (src/mod_fastcgi.c.3303) child signaled: 11

And the Full log file.

```
[26-Apr-2016 17:27:24 Asia/Jakarta] PHP Catchable fatal error:  Object of class mysqli_stmt could not be converted to string in /storage/emulated/legacy/pws/www/quran/search_func_array_ret.php on line 45
[26-Apr-2016 17:32:57 Asia/Jakarta] PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant query - assumed 'query' in /storage/emulated/legacy/pws/www/quran/search_func_array_ret.php on line 66
[26-Apr-2016 17:32:57 Asia/Jakarta] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: host in /storage/emulated/legacy/pws/www/quran/search_func_array_ret.php on line 30
[26-Apr-2016 17:32:57 Asia/Jakarta] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: user in /storage/emulated/legacy/pws/www/quran/search_func_array_ret.php on line 30
[26-Apr-2016 17:32:57 Asia/Jakarta] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: password in /storage/emulated/legacy/pws/www/quran/search_func_array_ret.php on line 30
[26-Apr-2016 17:32:57 Asia/Jakarta] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: database in /storage/emulated/legacy/pws/www/quran/search_func_array_ret.php on line 30
[26-Apr-2016 17:32:57 Asia/Jakarta] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object in /storage/emulated/legacy/pws/www/quran/search_func_array_ret.php on line 67
[26-Apr-2016 17:33:30 Asia/Jakarta] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: host in /storage/emulated/legacy/pws/www/quran/search_func_array_ret.php on line 30
[26-Apr-2016 17:33:30 Asia/Jakarta] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: user in /storage/emulated/legacy/pws/www/quran/search_func_array_ret.php on line 30
[26-Apr-2016 17:33:30 Asia/Jakarta] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: password in /storage/emulated/legacy/pws/www/quran/search_func_array_ret.php on line 30
[26-Apr-2016 17:33:30 Asia/Jakarta] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: database in /storage/emulated/legacy/pws/www/quran/search_func_array_ret.php on line 30
[26-Apr-2016 17:33:30 Asia/Jakarta] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object in /storage/emulated/legacy/pws/www/quran/search_func_array_ret.php on line 67
```

But I dont know why, this code is working fine,

```
    <?php

 if (isset($_GET['q'])){

       // error_reporting(-1);

     //  ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
      // ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); 
    //   error_reporting(E_ALL);






      $query = $_GET['q'];





   function search_aya($query) {

       require 'core/db.inc.php';

        $dbh  = new mysqli($host, $user, $password,  $database);

        if ($dbh->connect_error) {
            echo 'Unable to connect to database '. $dbh->connect_error;
        } else {



            if ($stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT id, sura, aya, text FROM bn_bengali WHERE MATCH(text) AGAINST(?) "))

               {
                $stmt->bind_param("s", $query);
                // executing the statement
                $stmt->execute();
                // binding the table columns Name and Email to the $Name and Email parameters respectively.
                $stmt->bind_result($id, $sura, $aya, $text);
                /* fetch associative array */



                while ($stmt->fetch()) {
                    echo $sura.'-'.$aya;
                    echo $text;
                    echo '<hr />';
                    } 


            } else {
                   echo "Prepare failed: (" . $dbh->errno . ") " . $dbh->error;
            }
        }

     } //ending function



        search_aya($query);

      /*  $stmt = search_aya($query);
        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
                    echo $sura.'-'.$aya;
                    echo $text;
                    echo '<hr />';
                    } */









} // end isset get q
else
{
     echo '<form action="" ><input type="text" name="q"><button>Search</button></form>';
}
    ?>
```

Comment: Which line have that error? You can remove `error_reporting(-1);` to know how line it is.

Comment: It's the the same thing "500 - Internal Server Error" after removing error_reporting(-1);

Comment: Use `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);` to check error in pgpe

Comment: start  your debug mode

Comment: Format this code, for a god sake!

Comment: @Marcos the `500` error is mostly the server's error, it doesn't show a PHP error at all.

Comment: Check your server's error log.

Comment: Showing the same message "500 - Internal Server Error" after adding ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
           ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); 
           error_reporting(E_ALL);      Its not showing no speacific error.

Comment: @C0dekid PHP can throw the errors in screen, if you turn on error reporting. That's why I tell it to OP. The alternative is crossing through the server error logs, but I think this guy don't know how to see the error logs (otherwise, this question shouldn't exists).

Comment: @Marcos You are right. I'm very new in php.

Comment: @Ganesh Patil How to turn debug mode on?

Comment: @HasanBinKarim : check apache error log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You appear to be using Palapa Web Server. To make sure you get actual error messages, open the menu in the app and go to "Web server settings" => "PHP settings" and make sure it's configured like this:

[image]

2) From the log you posted, it looks like you are using several variables which are not defined. I guess there are supposed to be defined in the file `core/db.inc.php` which you are `include`-ing.

- Change `include` to `require`. This way, PHP will throw an error when the file doesn't exist.
- Make sure the file actually exists.
- If the file does exist, it may exist in a different path than in which PHP is looking for it. PHP always resolves `include`/`require` statements relative to the *current directory* (which usually is the folder the original script is in, i.e. the one which you call in your URL), not the file the currently parsed file is in.

For example, you may have an URL like `http://localhost:8000/test.php` which runs `/storage/emulated/legacy/pws/www/test.php`. This file then uses `include('quran/search_func_array_ret.php');`. PHP would then load `/storage/emulated/legacy/pws/www/quran/search_func_array_ret.php`.

However, now `search_func_array_ret.php` uses `include('core/db.inc.php');`, and PHP will not look for `/storage/emulated/legacy/pws/www/quran/core/db.inc.php`, but instead for `/storage/emulated/legacy/pws/www/core/db.inc.php`!

You can test this theory by writing `die(getcwd());` at the top of the script temporarily - you will then see the path relative to which the `include`/`require` statements will be resolved.

If this was the problem, you either need to modify the path which is used in the `include`/`require` (tip: you can use `__DIR__` to reference the directory the currently parsed file is in, e.g. `require(__DIR__ . '/core/db.inc.php');`) or move the file to the correct location.

3) I am not sure whether `bind_result` will work across function boundaries as you are doing it right now. In case you find `$sura`, `$aya` and `$text` to be empty, you would need to move `$stmt->bind_result($id, $sura, $aya, $text);` out of the function, above the `while($stmt->fetch())` statement.

However, a better approach would then be using `return $stmt->get_result()->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);` inside your function, and then iterating over the result like this:

```
$results = search_aya($query);
foreach($results as $row) {
    echo $row['sura'] . '-' . $row['aya'];
    echo $row['text'];
    echo '<hr />';
}
```

**EDIT**: If your PHP version is older than 5.3.0, you can't use `fetch_all`. Instead, use this code inside your function:

```
$sqlResult = $stmt->get_result();
$results = array();
while($row = $sqlResult->fetch_assoc()) $results[] = $row;
return $results;
```

**EDIT2**: Actually, now that the advantage of `fetch_all` is gone anyway, you can also return `$stmt->get_result()` and change your loop outside to this:

```
$sqlResult = search_aya($query);
foreach($row = $sqlResult->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $row['sura'] . '-' . $row['aya'];
    echo $row['text'];
    echo '<hr />';
}
```

You can then delete the call to `bind_param` inside your function.

**EDIT3**: *I just realized that I made a mistake earlier, I forgot that `get_result` must first be called on the statement to receive a results object, which then allows calling `fetch_all` and `fetch_assoc`. I corrected the answer accordingly.*

Note that `get_result`, and afterwards `fetch_all` and `fetch_assoc` will only work if PHP can use a native SQL driver. If it doesn't work, you would need to keep using your old way, but just move the line `$stmt->bind_result($id, $sura, $aya, $text);` outside of the function.

Comment: Yes I made sure the db.inc.php do exist. Thi script is working fine if a fetech associative array inside the function. but when "return $stmt;" is writing iinside the function its not working

Comment: This is not what the log tells me. But if your problem happens only in this case, then it's exactly as I thought in point #3, so you just can't do it like this because `bind_result` will bind to local variables inside the function, which you don't have access to outside. The right solution is then using `fetch_all` and returning the data as I suggested. (_EDIT: The update you just posted, with the working version of the code, confirms my assumption. You can't bind to variables inside the function and then call `fetch` outside._)

Comment: return $stmt->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC); is adding inside the function is giving this error: error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetch_all() in /storage/emulated/legacy/pws/www/quran/search_func_array_ret.php on line 54

Comment: Appears you have a PHP version older than 5.3.0. I added the solution for older PHP to my answer (see the very bottom).

Comment: Alternatively, you can of course keep returning the `$stmt` itself, but instead of using `bind_result`, you just use the `while($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc())` loop *outside* of the function, while you go over the actual results. So it would be similar to your existing code but just using `fetch_assoc`. I will add this to my answer as well.

Comment: Its saying the same error like this "Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetch_assoc() in /storage/emulated/legacy/pws/www/quran/search_func_array_ret.php on line 58" after adding  $results = array();
while($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()) $results[] = $row;
return $results;

Comment: I'm very sorry, I just realized I made a mistake and forgot that you first need to get a results object to call `fetch_all` or `fetch_assoc` on. I corrected my answer. Please try using `fetch_all` again, but this way with the updated code I posted above (including `get_results`), and if it doesn't work, try the `fetch_assoc` method again (again with the updated code I posted), and if it still doesn't work, see my "EDIT3". Sorry for misleading you.

Comment: Great! Now It's working Perfectly. Thanks a lot for solving my problem